# Typescript Snippets on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I would like to know if any of you guys know a way to enable the following feature on Visual Studio (either a hidden setting or an extension):

I'm used to javascript development on Visual Studio where if I type:
**"if"** on the text editor, it shows me a popup ("code snippet for an if statement"). Pressing ENTER the following is added:

```
if (true) {

}
```

This is not available for typescript files!

These snippets are really useful and this is just a simple example

Another basic feature I'm missing is *"braces auto completion"*.

I am not sure if there is a way to enable it or not, but really would like these basic features available.

This also applies for the newly released Visual Studio 2015. On the other hand, Visual Studio Code seems to handle it very well.

Comment: The specific feature is 'auto complete'.

Comment: @bob It seems to me that we do have 'auto complete', while I'm coding i get 'hints' from my code (function names/etc) and pressing TAB auto completes them. The feature I'm missing seems different to me.

Comment: This is a current issue pending and has been reported on github
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1484

Answer (score 5):

There is an issue on Github about being able to use Javascript snippets in Typescript files, and to make the Snippet Code Manager being able to recognize Typescript as a Language.
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/312