# Can I create code snippets in Visual Studio 2015 for TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

I think the answer is "no" since there is some product level configuration required, but I really don't know. I'd like to create a code snippet for Angular 1.x directives written in TypeScript.

I've seen similar questions asking about this (e.g. here: [Typescript Snippets on Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179582/typescript-snippets-on-visual-studio)) but the way they are phrased and answered could be interpreted to mean that MSFT just hasn't gotten around to including some of the common snippets with TS as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can in VS 15 preview 4 or VS Code.
[TypeScript snippets in VS](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/312)

**Update:**
Microsoft team just updated Milestone for snippets in VS to VS 15 preview 5.
*See my comment and the answer in upper link.*